# PHP connection to H2DB H2 database

Tags: php, h2

How can I connect PHP to an H2 database, so far I tried starting the embedded server with a

```
$ java -cp h2-1.3.172.jar org.h2.tools.Server
  Web Console server running at http://127.0.1.1:8082 (others can connect)
  TCP server running at tcp://127.0.1.1:9092 (only local connections)
  PG server running at pg://127.0.1.1:5435 (only local connections)
```

installing the pg-sql module under ubuntu

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

then in my php I have the following

```
$conn = pg_connect("host=127.0.1.1 port=5435 dbname=/home/frank/testdb user=sa password=");
```

Also tried different ports: 5435, 9092, different host: localhost, 127.0.0.1 but nothing, the returned connection is null or the script hangs.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

pg_connect is used to connect to PostrgeSQL database server, not for H2DB. Those are completely different products and are not compatibile

To connect to H2 you can use php-java bridge and some custom java class to expose required functionalities to php client

Comment: H2 provides PostgreSQL compatibility and according to some forums using it is the only way to circumvent the lack of a proper driver under PHP for H2. If you have a working example with php-java-bridge please share it, so far no one managed to do it.

Comment: The trick is that you can not serialize resources, so it's impossible to do connection-related stuff and you must add one more abstraction layer. For example you can't do SELECT query and fetch resultset. You must do SELECT on Java side, use some ORM to convert resultset to objects and then you can send those objects back to PHP

Answer (score 1):

I had it working last year while executing the PHP code in a Java servlet. My experiment is available at https://github.com/webdevelopersdiary/jamp . It's backed by Quercus, and redirects PHP database connection attempts to H2 (at least it does for MySQL, haven't tested for PSQL, but it may do the same in that case). Also note that H2's "compatibility mode" is very rudimentary, it still breaks on pretty standard PSQL stuff that you feed it.